# Bash script to produce a "circular string"?

Tags: bash

Sorry for the awful title -- not sure how else to describe what I want to achieve.

Been trying to make a Bash script for the past couple days to achieve a very simple effect, but I cannot figure out how!

The command line arguments for the script are: (1) a string of length `n`, (2) an integer "target length" `N`, and (3) an integer offset `M`. Additionally, it can be assumed that `M,N < n`. All I need the program to do is the following:

1. If `M+N < n`, it should print `N` chars of the string starting at index `M`.
   `./script.sh "Hello world!" 5 3` should print `lo wo`,
   `./script.sh "Hello world!" 9 0` should print `Hello wor`,
   etc.
2. Otherwise (i.e. if `M+N >= n`), it should print up to the end of the string, followed by however many chars from the start of the string are required to meet the target length `N`.
   `./script.sh "Hello world!" 5 10` should print `d!Hel`,
   `./script.sh "Hello world!" 11 6` should print `world!Hello`,
   etc.

The resulting effect is a string that is either cut off short or "wrapped" such that it is always of the target length `N`.

It is step #2 in particular that is what has me stumped. I'm sure it's probably a simple case of doing some fancy stuff with substring syntax, but I've yet to figure it out. I would love to post code, but I haven't even thought of the pseudocode that would make this work yet; that's how stuck I am..

Comment: To me, `script.sh string index length` seems more "conventional" than `script.sh string length index`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the assumption that `M` and `N` are less than the length of the string, this becomes really easy. The actual length of the string doesn't matter; if you repeat it twice in a row, any substring using the values of `N` and `M` will be in range and doesn't need checks to see if it wraps or not:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

circular() {
    local str="$1$1"
    printf "%s\n" "${str:$3:$2}"
}

str='Hello world!'
circular "$str" 9 0
circular "$str" 5 3
circular "$str" 5 10
circular "$str" 11 6
```

Comment: Absolutely genius man! I totally didn't even think about just duping the input string, but it's such a simple solution.. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @OhFiveight I had some overengineered general purpose thing mostly done, and then realized it didn't need to be complicated given the constraints.